# df.set_index() makes weird objects in dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with setting index to my dataframe. Lets say that I have a dataframe with many things. When I want to access some record, everything is fine and the output is shown below:

```py
loads['LoadNodes'][1]
```

Output:

```py
'[]'
```

But problem is when I am trying to set index from one column data.

```py
multi = loads.set_index('SubProjectId')
multi['LoadNodes'][32213] #that index corresponds that one with 1 above
```

Output:

```py
SubProjectId
32213    []
32213    []
Name: LoadNodes, dtype: object
```

Why is that? Why empty list converts into such object?

Comment: All unknown types are 'object' in pandas. Read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example